# How to declare variable for DataGridviewColumn Type?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, variable-declaration, datagridviewcolumn

This must be simple, but I couldn't figure it out even after reading [Microsoft's specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.7.2).

How do I store DataGridViewColumn type in a declared variable? It has to provide a collection of types, similar to declaring variable for DataGridViewContentAlignment:

```
Dim GridAlignment as DataGridViewContentAlignment          ' declare

GridAlignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter  ' set
```

So it should be something like:

```
Dim GridColType1 as DataGridViewColumn      ' declare variable (how?)
Dim GridColType2 as DataGridViewColumn      ' declare variable (how?)

' To use variable like this:
GridColType1 = DataGridViewColumn.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn    ' set it as TextBox column
GridColType2 = DataGridViewColumn.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn   ' set it as ComboBox column
```

At this stage, no DataGridView exist, it's a definition to store for dynamic generation and I need the correct declaration in order to use it in PropertyGrid.

**EDIT:**
For another idea, here is what VS has in GUI when adding/editing DataGridView Column:
[image]

So it's the *ColumnType* declaration with the collection shown in the listbox, I'm looking for.

Comment: `Dim column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()`

Comment: Nope. It's not the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn that I need to declare, but the collection, which this type is member of. It's the same collection that appears in a combobox in Add column to dataGridView dialogue using GUI in VS.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Well, I thought the code is self-speaking, but I added an image from VS. That is actually exactly what I need to achive and since I'm using PropertyGrid, the datatype of the property has to be what's here labeled as *ColumnType*. It then populates itself the selection in ListBox.

Comment: Are you looking for something like what is shown in the first image here: [Animate Images in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49742207/7444103)? A custom `DataGridViewColumn` type that can be selected from Column Type selector?

Comment: That is a nice answer of yours, @Jimi! I'm not looking for custom type, I'm looking for the default collection/declaration of ColumnType, pretty much as shown in my example and your answer with the DataGridViewContentAlignment which can be set i.e. to MiddleCenter. Simply, that is the only way I can provide it to PropertyGrid property. Your answer gave me an idea that I could create a new class using "Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn", but perhaps I'm missing a simple way, such as that with the Alignment?

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you want to implement, in code, a type selector like the one presented by the DGV when you want to specify the type of a Column, using something that replicates the functionality of the ComboBox. Let's say, an *Enumerator switch* that returns a Column type. Is it something like this?

Comment: Yes @Jimi, that's pretty close. If you declare a variable of DataGridViewContentAlignment type, then when setting a value, it gives you options like TopLeft, MiddleCenter, etc. When you provide this variable to the PropertyGrid, it handles this property correctly, providing a list of those alignments in the property's line as a listbox. That works with all properties tried and should with ColumnType too - exaclty as in the picture I've included, but it generates the listbox on it's own. But I'm failing to provide the PropertyGrid property with a correct type of variable.

Comment: Yes, but, to what end? Are you building some kind of *configurator* for a generic DataGridView at Design Time? Or is it a Custom Designer? Or is this meant to be interpreted/assigned to in code at run-time?

Comment: Yes, you can call it a Configurator, I suppose. A DGV configuration is only a part of a bigger conf. set. I'm refactoring working module to use PropertyGrid, because it looks way more efficient and organized in handling large property sets. What you set in the configurator affects how a DataGridView will look and behave when it's instance is dynamically assembled. The current model saves integer representing a ColumnType and this is represented i.e. as 1=DataGridViewTextBoxColumn. Configurator may run (saving to DB) in the same runtime assy as the dynamic form (reading properties from DB).

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems the best and easiest way is to define custom Enum.

```
Public Enum DataGridViewColumnType
    NotSetError = 0
    TextBoxColumn = 1
    ImageColumn = 2
    CheckBoxColumn = 3
    ComboBoxColumn = 4
    ButtonCOlumn = 5
End Enum
```

Then I can set a variable of that type:

```
Public GridColType As DataGridViewColumnType
```

Then it can be used in property:

```
<CategoryAttribute("Grid"), DefaultValueAttribute(""), DescriptionAttribute("Select column type"), DisplayName("Grid Column Type")>
Public Property PropGriColType() As DataGridViewColumnType
    Get
        Return GridColType
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As DataGridViewColumnType)
        GridColType = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

The result is then as desired:

[image]