# How to make a custom DataGridView cell in WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I know I jave to use a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to make custom cells. However, I don't know how I can make the lay-out of this custom column? I want to add a collapse button and multiple lables underneath eachother.

Do I have to make a new (custom) WinForms User Control or Component?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is complicated.  You need to make a custom DataGridView Column class and then handle a number of  different methods.  Do a search for Custom DataGridView Column.

Comment: The Column doesn't necessarily be a `TextBoxColumn`, it can be a generic `DataGridViewColumn`. See the example here: [Animate Images in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49742207/7444103) (don't mind that it's a different .Net language, it's the same thing). The example creates a custom Column that contains a custom Cell, derived from `DataGridViewImageCell` and applies the methods of the `ImageAnimator` class. You just need to override some of the defult methods (`Clone()` is mandatory). Your custom Column also appears among the standard columns in the DGV's designer (see the image).

Comment: Thanks @Jimi! I wanted to put a couple of elements (image and textfields) inside a cell. If I make a UserControl, I can also design this. However, if I try a DataGridView element (e.g. TextBoxColumn) I can't use the designer. Any idea how to?

Comment: The DataGridViewCell uses a TypeConverter (derived from `ExpandableObjectConverter`). You have to provide your own TypeConverter. Then, the Public Properties of your custom Column appear in the PropertyGrid that is used to show the properties of each Column type (as you can notice, these are slightly different in each Column type: the ButtonColumn has  `FlatStyle` and `UseColumnTextForButtonValue`, for example). You can use one of these properties to setup a custom designer for your custom Cell.

Comment: @Jimi This is a bit old but I was following some advice and still need some guidance